# Why won't my Ubuntu server install Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I have an older Ubuntu server with a Rails app running on version 2.3.5 that I'd like to move to version 2.3.8. The server doesn't seem to know that there is an update available, no matter how many times I run a "gem update" or "gem update --system" or "update_rubygems"

```
root@server:~# gem install rails -v 2.3.8
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository
root@server:~# gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-2.3.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-2.3.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-2.3.5...
```

RubyGems 1.3.5 is installed.

I don't remember having to do anything special for any of my other servers when making this upgrade.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org` with `--source` and without `-v`.

Comment: That worked, Adrian! Thanks! Can you make that an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```

with --source and without -v.